# The probability of random subsets cover the set

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Set $A_{n} = \lbrace1, 2, 3, ..., n\rbrace$

Each possible subset of $A_{n}$ has a probability $p$ to be an element of
set $B_{n}$.

How much is the probability of set $C_{n}$, which is the union of all elements of $B_{n}$, is $A_{n}$?

Is there any other famous equal problem in combinatorics?

Comment: Erh ... No polynomial time algorithm without heuristics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)

Comment: The problem looks like Set Cover. But it is not. Set cover is about minimum set of covering subsets. I'm looking for "how many" combinations of subsets in the S are covering U? Then I can deduce probability!

Comment: R Zu, I appreciate your answer and comments. Regarding your comment, suppose that we know the answer for Set Cover Problem and it is solvable here. can we infer the answer of above question? I mean can we convert the problem to the famous Set Cover?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the problem:

- Set $A_{n} = \lbrace1, 2, 3, ..., n\rbrace$
- Each possible subset of $A_{n}$ has a probability $p$ to be an element of
  set $B_{n}$.
- Find probability that set $C_{n}$, which is the union of all elements of $B_{n}$, is $A_{n}$.

Solution:

For $n = 1$, $P(C_1 = A_{1}) = p$.

Randomly choose one of the 4 possible cases for $B_1$, which may have the empty set as an element.

Construct $B_{n + 1}$ by including all elements of $B_{n}$ and then deciding if the $2^{n}$ "new" subsets of $A_{n + 1}$ would be included in $B_{n + 1}$.

The new subsets all contains the new element $n + 1$. If at least one of the new subset is chosen, then $C_{n + 1} = A_{n + 1}$. Therefore, $P(C_{n + 1} = A_{n + 1} | C_n = A_n) = 1 - (1 - p)^{2^{n}}$.

By induction, $P(C_n = A_{n}) = \prod_{n} [1 - (1 - p)^{2^{n - 1}}] $

Comment: I do not study mathematics regularly. Is this correct?

Comment: The term "Each possible" in the second bullet is not correct. In my problem, S is just including a number of all subsets of U.